# create empty NSDate object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, nsdate

Is this ok?

```
NSDate *myDate;
```

Because I used something like this before:

```
NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

if (something)
     myDate = thisDate;
else
     myDate = thatDate;

[myFunction initWithDate:myDate];
```

I always got "Value stored to 'myDate' during its initialization is never read". If I do something like this

```
if (something)
     NSDate *myDate = thisDate;
else
     NSDate *myDate = thatDate;

[myFunction initWithDate:myDate];
```

I get "Unused variable 'myDate'" and "'myDate' undeclared (first use in this function)"

How does the release look like? Autorelease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to point to a pre-existing date, you could do something like this:

```
NSDate *myDate = something ? thisDate : thatDate;
[myFunction initWithDate:myDate];
```

or even

```
[myFunction initWithDate:something ? thisDate : thatDate];
```

However, to more clearly answer your question, yes, this could should be fine:

```
NSDate *myDate;

if (something) {
    myDate = thisDate;
} else {
    myDate = thatDate;
}
```

You can also initialize myDate to nil (`myDate = nil`), if you want.

As far as memory management goes, you're just setting a pointer -- you're not creating a new object, or taking ownership (via `retain`) of an existing object -- so you don't need to use `release` or `autorelease` at all.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. If thisDate or thatDate is released myDate is pointing to nowhere. So I depend on the them. I think they are created by convenience functions (dateFromComponents/dateByAddingTimeInterval returns new NSDate objects), so I hope they are autoreleased. Nothing to do with the memory management here?

Answer (score 0):

your first try was close

```
NSDate *myDate;

if (something)
     myDate = thisDate;
else
     myDate = thatDate;

[myFunction initWithDate:myDate];
```

First line declares an NSDate variable named `myDate`. Then you run your test and set the value of myDate appropriately.

Comment: That's it, thanks. Sorry can't mark both answers as solution.